# How can I quickly check ASP.NET memory footprint?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

When debugging an ASP.NET app in VS, is the WebDev.WebService.EXE process (viewable in Task Manager) a good indicator of memory footprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty good but then memory utilization is always a bit of a guess anyhow.  Perhaps a more accurate way to tell would be to use [perfmon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516%28VS.71%29.aspx).